# ffmpeg меняет цвет видео

Tags: ffmpeg

Подскажите можно ли добавить какую то настройку, чтобы видео при конвертации не меняло свой цвет? При конвертации с gif проблем не было. Конвертирую с mp4 в webm такой командой

```
./ffmpeg -i takeOutCard4.mp4  -c:v libvpx -minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis takeOutCard4.webm
```

Пробовала добавлять качество libvpx -qmax 63 и еще много всего и ничего не помогает, фон видео становится темнее немного чем в оригинале

Comment: Покажите скриншоты с разным цветом что ли, а то плохо понятно о чём речь

Comment: И да, проверяйте оба ролика через ffplay - плееры тоже могут портить цвет, а плеер ffplay вроде не портит

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Кидаю ссылку на скриншот цвета http://joxi.ru/8236DxGT6ey1Wm. Видео вставляется в браузер.

Comment: Проверьте в ffplay и в разных браузерах, а то за гугл-хромом я тоже замечал порчу цвета. Возможно, проблема не в ffmpeg

Comment: к сожалению мне файл нужен именно для Хрома и я его уже конвертировала только не с mp4 а с gif и проблемы с цветом не было

Comment: А вы всё равно проверьте, это улучшит понимание природы проблемы

Comment: в FireFox видео так же другого цвета. Другие браузеры webm вроде как не принимают

Comment: А в ffplay? Или его у вас нет?

Comment: спасибо, настройки у дизайнера неправильные были при создании. Решила эту проблему путем до параметра ffmpeg eq=brightness=0.03